# Как стилизовать посещенную ссылку?

Tags: css3, ссылки, меню

Есть три пункта меню. 
[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/Yuri_Fedorov/pen/LdRdPX)

```css
ul
  list-style: none
  margin: 0
  padding-left: 5%
  padding-top: 15px
a
  text-decoration: none
  color: white
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px
  border: 1px solid
  border-radius: 15px
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease
  -o-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease
a:active
  background: blue

li
  float: left
  margin-right: 5px
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link1">Маршруты</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link2">О нас</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link3">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Когда курсор зажат на кнопке (`a:active`), то применяется `"background: blue"`
Как сделать так, чтобы когда отодвигаешь курсор с кнопки она оставалась синей?

Answer (score 1):

селектор a:visited. дальше такие же действия, как и с a:active

Comment: Ваше решение не подойдет. Задача другая.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1):

В рамках этого ответа нельзя дать однозначный воспроизводимый пример, по этому в сниппете ответа есть jQuery код который работает при переходе только на действительную страницу html , прошу сообщество ruSO простить за оплошность за ссылку на облако.майл.ру : https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6455/GyGH53SM1 в котором лежит сама реализация перехода по ссылкам с сохранения активного пункта меню и именно так это и называется "активный пункт меню" **при условии что я верно понял**

**скриншот работы скрипта после сниппета**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var url = document.location.href;
  $.each($(".menu a"), function() {
    if (this.href == url) {
      $(this).addClass('focus');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.focus {
  background: blue;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='ru'>

<head>
  <title>
    playground
  </title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.html">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Команда</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <h1>Главная</h1>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ

Comment: @YuriFedorov помогло ?

Comment: Не самом деле все оказалось намного легче. Сделал все через псевдокласс :focus.

Comment: Этот псевдокласс работать будет только когда нажали и всё т.е если кликнуть в другом месте это пропадёт другими словами я хотел показать на фокус но это вообще не то ...не для этих целей он применяется